# Проверка checkboxes на jquery при нажатии

Tags: javascript, jquery

есть поля

```html
<div class="multiselect">
  <div class="selectBox" onclick="showCheckboxesxf_8()">
    <select style="display: none;">
   <option>Выбрать</option>
  </select>

    <div class="chzn-container chzn-container-single chzn-container-single-nosearch" style="width: 180px;" title="">
      <a class="chzn-single">
        <span>Выбрать</span>
        <div><b></b></div>
      </a>
      <div class="chzn-drop">
        <div class="chzn-search">
          <input type="text" autocomplete="off" readonly="">
        </div>
        <ul class="chzn-results">
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="overSelect"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="close" class="checkboxesxf_8">
    <div class="checkbox__text">
      <input type="checkbox" class="exfield exgroup1" name="xf_8[]" id="xf_8_0" value="3" checked="checked">
      <label class="lb-checkbox checkbox" for="xf_8_0">Парам парам</label>
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox__text">
      <input type="checkbox" class="exfield exgroup1" name="xf_8[]" id="xf_8_1" value="4">
      <label class="lb-checkbox checkbox" for="xf_8_1">Парам парам 2</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Как сделать проверку чтобы при нажатии на "Парам парам 2" checked пермещалось на него, скрывался блок "button" с классом "xf_1" и появлялся с классом "xf_7", а при нажатии на "парам парам" наборот

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для одиночного выбора обычно используются радиокнопки `<input type="radio">`

```js
$('.switcher').change(function() {
  $('.switch-target').hide();
  $($(this).data('target')).fadeIn();
  $('.switcher').not(this).prop('checked', false);
})
```

```css
fieldset {
  border: none;
  height: 60px;
}

.label_block {
  display: block;
}

.collapsed {
  display: none;
}

.label__title {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<fieldset>
  <label id="param1" class="label_block switch-target">
    <span class="label__title">Выбрать</span>
    <input type="text" />
  </label>  
  <label id="param2" class="label_block switch-target collapsed">
    <span class="label__title">Выбрать</span>
    <select>
     <option>1</option>
     <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
    </select>
  </label>
</fieldset>

<label class="label_block">
  <input type="checkbox" class="switcher" data-target="#param1" checked>
  <span>Параметр 1</span>
</label>
<label class="label_block">
  <input type="checkbox" class="switcher" data-target="#param2">
  <span>Параметр 2</span>
</label>
```